# How can I email an attachment from the command line

Tags: command-line, email, files

Is it possible to email attachments from the command line?

If possible, I'd like something as simple as:

```
mail -a myfile.txt -t me@example.com -s "Here's my file"
```

Comment: The default ubuntu command line mail user-agent `mail` (aka `mailx`) is MIME ignorant therefore cannot handle attachments in any way that isn't 1980ish. This is a good question, I'm looking for the canonical Canonical MUA; more to come.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Of all the mail user agents in the Ubuntu repository, it appears that [mutt](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=mutt) is the command-line MUA that is blessed with Long Term Support.

According to [the manual](http://www.mutt.org/doc/man_page.html), you can do something exactly like:

```
mutt -a myfile.txt -s "Here's my file" -- me@example.com
```

except it won't go anywhere since one also needs a Mail Transfer Agent. Popular ones are:

- the venerable sendmail
- postfix
- exim4
- qmail
- nullmailer

and the only ones that Canonical seems to support are postfix (thanks for the correction Steve) and [exim4](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=exim4).

One could also say that [xdg-email](http://portland.freedesktop.org/wiki/EmailConfig) is also a proper Ubuntu MUA, but it is a bare-bones front end which only executes *your preferred MUA* on your behalf.

If you'd like advice on which MTA might be suitable for your use, perhaps open another question here.

Comment: Great question, thanks. You prompted me to get mail working on my box. I used nullmailer MTA to blindly relay to my ISP, and the example `mutt` command worked as advertised. Incidentally nullmailer has a fake sendmail front-end so that most programs that expect to talk to sendmail get shuffled off to a real MTA with zero effort from me.

Comment: msw, I'm not quite sure why you're claiming exim4 is the only one canonical supports, postfix is also in main and is what is enabled if you select the Mail Server task selection from the ubuntu-server install. I believe exim4is the debian default MTA, and in the past, packaging preferences may have caused it to be pulled in by default, but for a while now, postfix is definitely the preferred MTA in Ubuntu.

Comment: Oh, and also note that if you went with bsd mail/mailx as your (non-mime aware) MUA, you would still need an MTA of some kind to actually send the mail. But mutt's better for you anyway. :-)

Answer (score 14):

I had bad trouble with sending attachment files, too. When I sent an email without attachment, it was successful but was not with attachment. This problem was existent with `sendemail`, `mutt`, `mail`, `mailx` , `uuencode` commands.

Fortunately, It was solved funnily. I use Gmail for sending email. You can configure your gmail for sending emails via commands in terminal as declared at 
http://www.linuxandlife.com/2013/01/send-email-from-linux-terminal.html .

You can send a text email using:

```
mail -s "hello" RECEIVE@mail.com < /home/masoud/YOURFILE.txt
```

but you **can't** send same file as attachment as below:

```
mail -s "hello" RECEIVE@mail.com -a /home/masoud/YOURFILE.txt
```

or:

```
mail -s "hello" -a /home/masoud/YOURFILE.txt RECEIVE@mail.com
```

Finally, I understood that only this format could send an attachment:

```
echo "your message here" | mail -s "title" -a /home/masoud/YOURFILE.txt RECEIVE@mail.com
```

Funnily, the difference is existence of the "echo" command.

### Update: 201808

Seems that the `-a` option has been changed with **Uppercase** `-A` for attachment now. The `-a` seems to be for changing header according to [doc](https://mailutils.org/manual/html_section/mail.html)

Comment: Excellent! Thanks. I was trying to send my `.zshrc` file to someone and though I use `mail` a lot to send quick messages, trying to sent an attachment wasn't working. I just needed confirmation that it was possible to realize that *argument order* is very important.

This worked for me:
`mail -s "zshrc" -a ~/.zshrc username@example.com` ...of course I still had to type the message body and hit `ctrl+d` on the last blank line.

Comment: Using `mail username@example.com -a ~/.zshrc` did "work" in that it sent the message but it did not send the file. Had I tried `mail username@example.com -a ~/.zshrc -s 'zshrc'` it would have been obvious that the params after the recipient address were being ignored.

Comment: @Masoud lnk is broken... wanted to update it, but you know better what documentation you provided so I let it to you

Answer (score 6):

I found that the command and parameters have been changed recently.

If your want to send your attachments with this command:

```
mail -s "your subject" you@gmail.com -A /your/attachment/absolute/path < /home/you/message.txt
```

The option `attachment` should be `-A` which is CAPITAL `A`.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to send a file **from the shell**, but otherwise **use Thunderbird**.

In this case, try `thunderbird -remote ...` is useful - assuming thunderbird is usually running:

The command opens a mail compose window of a running thunderbird instance.
The "From" address is your **default address** configured in thunderbird.
Also, the existing **account settings** are used, there is no separate setup needed.

For a mail adressed to `you@example.com`, with subject "S", body "B", and an attachment `/some/absolute/file.txt`, the command is

```
thunderbird -remote "xfeDoCommand(composeMessage,subject='S',to='you@example.com',body='B',attachment='/some/absolute/file.txt')"
```

There are two problems:

The attached file needs to be given by an **absolute path**, which is tedious in practice. That can be handeled by using `readlink -f` to resolve relative paths:

```
thunderbird -remote "xfeDoCommand(composeMessage,subject='S',to='you@example.com',body='B',attachment='$(readlink -f file.txt)')"
```

Also, the command is to long. Use a shell script or shell function, with four arguments:

```
thunderbird-compose () {
    thunderbird -remote "xfeDoCommand(composeMessage,subject='$1',to='$2',body='$3',attachment='$(readlink -f $4)')"
}
```

With this function, the command becomes readable:

```
thunderbird-compose 'Some Subject' test@example.com 'Body of message' file1
```

will open a thunderbird "Write" **window with the attachment**, and From, To, Subject, and body text filled in. It can be **edited** before sending it.

Answer (score 2):

`heirloom-mailx` package in debian provides `mailx` command to send mime attachments easily. following works for me;

```
 mailx -a attachment.zip -s subject rctp@domain.to
```

Comment: This was the missing piece I needed; the `mail` and `mailx` included with RH-alikes has `-a` for file attachments, but the one included in Debian-alikes does not.

Answer (score 0):

I wish to add another answer which is used to add body text along with the attachment. Cheers!!

```
echo "This is the message body" | mutt -a "/path/to/file.to.attach" -s "subject of message" -- recipient@domain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

My version of `mail`, BSD mail, does not seem to support attachments (it's not mentioned anywhere in the manpage).

A hacky workaround is to send the attachment as uuencoded stream. Gmail will interpret this as two attachments, one called "noname" which is the uuencoded text and the other called "-" which carries the decoded version that can be opened by any program that recognizes the file type by its binary data. I don't know if this behavior is documented or applies for any other mail client, but if you don't want to install anything this is a quick hack.

```
uuencode image.jpg - |  mail -s "Subject line" user@example.net
```